# Shopping List in Python with Sorting

Tags: python, sorting, input, output, price

"Write a program to prompt the user to enter 5 items and their prices. The program should then sort the input from highest to lowest price and output the sorted data showing the item and the price."

Here is what I have so far, I have no idea what to do after this, if the user was to just enter the price, I would be okay, but the item name also has to be output:

```
print("Welcome To Shopping List!")

item1 = raw_input('Enter First Item')
item1price = int("Enter First Item Price:  ")

item2 = raw_input(input('Enter First Item'))
item2price = int(input("Enter Second Item Price:  "))

item3 = raw_input('Enter First Item')
item3price = int(input("Enter Third Item Price:  "))

item4 = raw_input('Enter First Item')
item4price = int(input("Enter Fourth Item Price:  "))

item5 = raw_input('Enter First Item')
item5price = int(input("Enter Fifth Item Price:  "))


data = [(item1, item1price), (item2, item2price), (item3, item3price),         (item4, item4price)]
data = [int(x) for x in data]
data.sort()
```

The output needs to look like this, sorted by highest to lowest price:

```
Coffee 4.99  
Kitchen 
Towel 1.75  
Butter 1.70  
Milk 0.45
```

I'm new to python so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Use `input()` in py3 and `raw_input()` in py2, not a mixture! `int()` without input on a string is also clearly failing. If you put this in a `for i in range(5)` loop, you'd save some code and help avoid these mistakes!

Comment: Get rid of all those numbered variables. You should be using a loop, and saving the data directly into a list of tuples.

Comment: Writing code by repeated copying and pasting [isn't a good plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). It makes the code more error-prone, long-winded, and harder to read. Notice that you've messed up the prompts to get the item names: they all say `raw_input('Enter First Item')`.  And `item1price = int("Enter First Item Price:  ")` will raise ValueError.

Comment: If you reorder the values in the tuples (price first) you can just sort the list containing the tuples in descending order and everything is fine. BTW, you won't get a value like `4.99` if you cast the price to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making 10 or more variables for your item and price, ask the user how many he/she wants. use that number to loop and store the inputs in a tuple then append to the list. use `'for'` loop again to display your data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

# Write a program to prompt the user to enter a number of  items and their prices.
# The program should then sort the input from highest to lowest price and
# output the sorted data showing the item and the price.

print("Welcome To Shopping List!")
numItems = input("How many items do you want? ")
myTup = ()
myList = []

for x in range(int(numItems)):
    itemName = input("Enter item name: ")
    itemPrice = input("Enter item price: ")
    myTup = (itemPrice, itemName)
    myList.append(myTup)

myList.sort()

for x in range(len(myList)): print(myList[x][1] + " = " + myList[x][0])
```

Comment: And where is the sorting of the data?